# Is there any way to compare the absolute values obtained from a field?

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to compare the absolute values obtained from a field?

Example.

Mitigated Risk = 24.50
Business Risk = -10.00

( it should not take into account -ve sign)

I tried this, But it is not working

```
Imports System.Math

If (((Math.Abs(Me.txt_mitigated_risk.Text)) > (Math.Abs(Me.txt_business_revenue_risk.Text))) Then

    Me.lbl_conf_message.Text = "Mitigated Risk value cannot be greater than Project Value."
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.Abs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx) requires a numeric parameter, while you are providing `Strings`. First convert the text of your textbox to the appropriate (numeric) type (it can be `Decimal`, `Double`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `SByte` or `Single`).

```
Dim mitigatedRisk As Decimal
Dim businessRisk As Decimal

If Decimal.TryParse(Me.txt_mitigated_risk.Text, mitigatedRisk) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(Me.txt_business_revenue_risk.Text, businessRisk) Then
    If Math.Abs(mitigatedRisk) > Math.Abs(businessRisk) Then
        Me.lbl_conf_message.Text = "Mitigated Risk value cannot be greater than Project Value."
    End If
Else
    ' The values in the textboxes are not valid decimals
End If
```